# Entity Framework Oracle Database Subquery with Max and group by

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hello Could anyone help in this question regarding entity framework I have the following query

```
select * from table_1 WHERE id in 
      (select max(id) as id from table_1 WHERE name <= :name
 and schoolId= :schoolId and when= :when GROUP BY numberofstudents ) and active <> 'D'";
```

I have a lot of options to use like I can make SP and call it entity framework will handle the type
I can use sql option in database.

but I need to do it with linq if possible,

I can't post the real example or any snippet of code here, I Apologize for that.

the query is almost similar to the real one.

my attempt

```
var results = _context.table_1.Where(d =>
                         d.id == _context.table_1.Where(x =>

                                        string.Compare(x.name , name ) <= 0 &&
                                        x.schoolId == schoolId &&
                                        x.when.Equals(when)
                                        
                                        )
                                        .Max(x => x.id))
                                        .Where(y => y.ACTIvE != "D")
                                        .Select(d => new DTO
                                         {
                                             //set of paramters for DTO 
                                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: `I need to do it with linq if possible`, in your example besides the actual query, where is your attempt at this so we can help you?

Comment: I added my attempt , the problem I can't use group by it break the query

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I added my trial when I use group by in the inner query i can't use select since I'll work with groups ? how can I solve this.

Comment: Sort by id descending, then group by id, and take first : .Where(y => y.ACTIvE != "D").OrderByDescending(x => x.id).GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(x => x.First())